# PHP Execution Mac OS X Yosemite Safari 8.0.8

Tags: php, safari, osx-yosemite

Executing php version 5.5.31 on Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.5, Safari 8.0.8.
When executing, instead of getting the php output, I am getting a listing of the php source code.

I am executing the code in my home directory/Sites.
I do not have .htaccess in this directory.

What do I need to do to get my php output to execute in Safari?

Comment: If you can, please share with us how you're executing these and what the output looks like.

Comment: what is the URL you are accessing your code from? it should start with `http://localhost/`